# How to move filtred data rows from table to another one using model

Tags: python, django, django-models, bulkinsert

I have two model classes A and B and I want to move somme rows from table A to B, I wonder how to do it properly.

The **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Code of the **views.py**

```
from models import A, B

def move(request):
    filtered_a = A.objects.filter(category=2)
    """
    Here I want to move filtered_a rows to B table,
    and how to deal with the id 
    """
```

Please I don't talk about migration, it's treatment that comes after click action, any clean and fast way to do it are welcome.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
def move(request):
    filtered_a = A.objects.filter(category=2)
    filtered_b = [B(**a) for a in filtered_a]
    B.objects.bulk_create(filtered_b)
```

this should do the trick. If your queryset is going to huge, i would suggest using iterator while looping through.

```
[B(**a) for a in filtered_a.iterator()]
```